# Sequential HTTP post requests in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am pushing sensor data to a mongoDB server using node.js and express. I'm pushing data around 5 times a second (using HTTP post requests).

I send aggregated sensor data.
My sensor data look like this

```
  transmission 1 - 1,2,3 
  transmission 2 - 4,5,6 
  transmission 3 - 7,8,9
```

After appending my data to database, it **sometimes** looks like this

*data array - 1,2,3,**7,8,9**,4,5,6*

As you can see 3rd transmission is appended before 2nd transmission

POST request handling parts of my server.js look like this

```
var app = require("express")();
app.post("/saveData", function(req, res){
  res.send("a");//sending acknowledgement  
      Data_From_NodeMCU = req.body.hello; //getting data from JSON object
      ////Some processing\\\\


      dbObject.updateOne(
      {name: "AKILA"}, 
      {'$push': {data :{$each: processed_data} }},
      function (err) {
                        if (err) 
                             {
                                console.log("DB error:");
                                console.log(err);
                              }                              
                      }
                        );        
    
});
```

It seems like what i want to achieve is, **once app.post is called, stop it from executing again until database is updated**. It maybe a basic problem but I'm new to this, any help would be very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [async's queue](https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#queue) with a concurrency of `1`. It will be something like this:

```
const app = require("express")();
const queue = require("async/queue");

const q = queue(function(task, cb) {
  dbObject.updateOne({name: "AKILA"}, 
    {'$push': {data :{$each: task.processed_data} }}, (err) => {
       if (err) console.log("DB error:", err);
       cb();
  });     
}, 1)

app.post("/saveData", function(req, res){
  res.send("a"); //sending acknowledgement  
  const Data_From_NodeMCU = req.body.hello; 
  const processed_data = processData(Data_From_NodeMCU);
  q.push({processed_data});   
});
```